# jQuery-AJAX: Checking if Data Exists, if not "POST"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I am trying to check if the data already exists in the JSON Array Object that is returned on 'GET'. IF the data already exists, I want it to ignore the data. If it does not exist I want it to "POST." Please help. It seems to be skipping the "POST" call.

```
  function POST(section){
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
     async : false,
        data: JSON.stringify(section),
        url: '/api/v2/help_center/en-us/categories/200384077/sections.json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        },// end headers
        success: function (newSection) {
            console.log("Congrats! We have inserted a new section", newSection);

        },
        error: function (xhr, errorText) {
            console.log('Error ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    })// end AJAX POST
    }

function addNewSection(name, description) {

    var section = { "section": { "position": 2, "name": name, "description": description, "content.translations.name": [{ "locale": "en-us" }] } };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/v2/help_center/categories/200384077/sections.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic" + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        },
        success: function (mySections) {

            var naming = mySections.sections;
            $.each(naming, function (i, result) {
              if( $.inArray(name, result) == -1)
              {
                console.log("This already exists", name);
              } 

                if( !$.inArray(name, result) == -1) {
              POST(section);
              }

            });

        } // end success function
    })// end AJAX GET


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this worked just perfectly!!

```
var match = false;
$.each(naming, function(i,v){
  if(v.name == name){
         match = true;
        return false;
    }
 });
 if(!match){
  POST(section);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!` from this:

```
if( !$.inArray(name, result) == -1)
```

So you have:

```
if ($.inArray(name, result) == -1)
```

What you wrote is basically a double negative.  `$.inArray` returns `-1` when it doesn't find anything.  You would never use `!` with `$.inArray` because it can never return `false`.

Comment: I used if( !$.inArray(name, result) == -1) if the data doesn't exist. then "POST." Is there a better way to write it? because If i use  if( $.inArray(name, result) == -1) again then i will insert duplicate data.

Comment: if( $.inArray(name, result) == -1) already literally means "If the name is NOT in the result array".  Isn't that when you want to post?

Comment: If you want it the other way, where you post only if the name IS in the array, you'd do if( $.inArray(name, result) >= 0).  Either way, you would never write !$.inArray as the function has no way of ever returning "false."  It returns -1 if it doesn't find anything, or an index (0 or higher) if it does find something.

Comment: When using >=0 it always says the data exists in the array even when it doesn't.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to post your code where that's happening, because there's something else going on.  If $.inArray comes back with 0 or greater, it found a match...there's no way for $.inArray to get it wrong.

Comment: I posted code. Not sure when It is not working with what i have currently written.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83578/discussion-between-ben-fried-and-darius-castillo).